# Make Azure Pipeline Condition abstract

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, devops, pipeline

I have used the following script in my Azure Build Pipeline. Here I like to use the condition more abstract. For example, I wanted to give some boolean input to condition based on some external computations I made already (Maybe, Should I use a property file or some new task inside pipeline) rather than keeping the computations tightly coupled.

```
  - script: |
              docker load < $(Pipeline.Workspace)/docker/cache.tar
              docker tag "test.com/${{parameters.image}}:cached" "test.com/${{parameters.image}}:$(Build.BuildNumber)"
            displayName: Restore Docker image cache
            condition: and(not(canceled()), eq(variables.DOCKER_CACHE_RESTORED, 'true'))
```